# Proof complexity and computational complexity

Tags: reference-request, proof-explanation, computational-complexity, turing-machines, descriptive-complexity

What is the  relation  between  proof  complexity  and  computational complexity (Turning machine)?  Is there any reference  around  these  stuff?

Comment: Yes: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19336/start-learning-proof-complexity (good place to start)

Comment: I am not the starter of this,  I wish  to know How complexity defined  in Turning machine  has  a proof side correspondence.

Comment: I know. I posted the link above as it provides resources to learn about proof complexity.